# When loading view tab-bar not displayed - noob question

Tags: iphone, xcode

I Have a TabView control, and when the user clicks on the tab item, the view will load.

When the view is loaded, there is a button on the view, and when i click on the button, another view gets loaded, i used the following code to load the view:

```
    NextView *next = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:next animated:NO];
```

But when the view loads, the tab bar items are not displayed. It loads on top of the tab bar items. how can i make the view pop out with the tab bar items ?

Answer (score 0):

NextView *next = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:next animated:YES];

if you are using presentModalViewController  then you can't display the tabBar instead you can use pushViewController

Comment: NextView *next = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:nil]; [self.navigationController pushViewcontroller:next animated:YES];

Comment: It says it doesn't respond to pushviewcontroller. why is this ? any clue ?